# Can I stop my for loop in the given code from printing the incorrect number of times without getting rid of the for loop itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chr, ord

```
codeword = input('Enter codeword : ')
codeword = codeword.lower().replace(" ", "")
for i in codeword:
    old = (chr(ord(i)))

encrypt = input('Enter text to encrypt : ')
encrypt = encrypt.lower().replace(" ", "")
for i in encrypt:
    new = (chr(ord(i)))
for i in encrypt:
    out = ord(old) + ord(new) -96 
print(chr(out))
```

Above is my full code so far. However, if I enter 'hi' for both codeword and encrypt, all that is printed, is 'r'. Is anyone able to point out my mistake, as I have tried everything I can think of, I am fairly certain that my error lies within the for loop, But if I do 'for i in encrypt + codeword' it prints 'r' still. I never knew something so simple once explained, can hold so many difficulties.

Many thanks.

*I have edited the code and shown it below, yet I am still struggling. I know there are many people out there who know this, but I am new, I have tried to research but I failed to find anything*

```
codeword = input('Enter codeword : ')
codeword = codeword.lower().replace(" ", "")
old = codeword[-1]

encrypt = input('Enter text to encrypt : ')
encrypt = encrypt.lower().replace(" ", "")
new = encrypt[-1]
for i in new:
    print(chr(ord(old)+ ord(new)-96))
```

*I have once again done further editing and produced a program that does near enough what I want, yet there is a slight issue, it prints it twice, but if I get rid of the `for loop` I will prevent the program from printing anything at all.

```
codeword = input('Enter codeword : ')
codeword = codeword.lower().replace(" ", "")

encrypt = input('Enter text to encrypt : ')
encrypt = encrypt.lower().replace(" ", "")

for i in codeword+encrypt:
    print(chr(ord(i)+ ord(i)-96))
```

Unfortunately, if I put 'hi' as both the codeword and as encrypt, it prints,
    p
    r
    p
    r

Comment: `chr(ord(i))` just gives you `i`. That for loop is equivalent to `new=encrypt[-1]`. Same with the first for loop

Comment: Thank you, I am still having difficulties with the issue of it only printing the last character though.

Comment: All you're doing is reassigning `old` on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You only have a single letter in `old` and `new` so your third loop will just do the same operation `len(encrypt)` times which will give you a single character

Comment: We need more information to fully answer your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If I was to enter 'abc' as the codeword. And 'cde' for encrypt. I want to use the ord() function to find the values of each letter together like so, h=8, i=9, and the same for encrypt. The program should add these together to make, 16, 18. After that, the chr() function should convert them to 'p' and 'r'. However, it is only printing 'r' and not 'p'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem doesn't exist in the third for loop. It exists in the first two. You are setting old and new to the last character of `codeword` and `encrypt`. You then loop over encrypt for the third one. You only have one value for `old` and `new` so you perform the same operation `length of encrypt` times which will give you a single character or possibly an error.

```
codeword = input('Enter codeword : ')
codeword = codeword.lower().replace(" ", "")

old = codeword[-1]
print (old)

encrypt = input('Enter text to encrypt : ')
encrypt = encrypt.lower().replace(" ", "")

new = encrypt[-1]
print (new)

for i in encrypt:

    out = ord(old) + ord(new) - 96
    print (out, old, new, i) 
print(chr(out))

Enter codeword : Hello
o

Enter text to encrypt : Hello
o

126 o o h
126 o o e
126 o o l
126 o o l
126 o o o

~
```

There's nothing more I can do since you haven't described the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the problem a lot better now, I will work on the code and try to fix it. I really appreciate your time and effort mate.